What cartoon series featured barnyard animals in airplanes?
I watched a cartoon series in the early- to mid-1990's featuring a war between barnyard animals.

The war took place on the farm.
The animals flew around in airplanes.
The series had a McDonald's tie-in with Happy Meal toys.
I believe the pigs were the main protagonists, but they might have been warthogs.

Does anyone know the name of the series?

I think this is likely Barnyard Commandos (1990)
Wikipedia

Barnyard Commandos is an action figure line created by toy designer James Groman for American Greetings Corporation and produced by Playmates in 1989. A thirteen-episode French-American animated series was based on the figures the following year
The property is based around the concept of farm animals who consumed radioactive materials left over from an abandoned military experiment, mutating them into hyper-intelligent, anthropomorphic paramilitary troops. This consists of two "hilariously harmless" opposing teams: the R.A.M.S. (Rebel Army of Military Sheep) and the P.O.R.K.S. (Platoon of Rebel Killer 
  Swine).




